# Weird temperature showing up in one of my SSD drives (Gnome Disk Utility)

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, temperature

my Kingston A400 SDD drive is showing an anomalous temperature of 92°C according to the disk utility. While my other SDD, which is a Hikvision C100, is showing 35°C which is reasonable.

[image: Kingston A400 showing up a temperature of 92°C/198°F]

[image: Normal temp showing up on the Hikvision SSD]

Any reason why this might be happening? I have Windows 11 installed on the Kingston SDD and Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on the Hikvision.
Thanks.

Comment: Based on [the data sheet for your SSD](https://www.kingston.com/datasheets/SA400S37_en.pdf), the unit would likely fail beyond 75ºC. You may find more accurate temperature info with the `hddtemp` utility, but one thing to note is that not all SSDs include temperature data as part of the SMART API queries. As a result, some SSDs may always show as being a certain temperature (usually 30ºC, 99ºC, or 100ºC) 

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is a bit old like the others, there is no clear answer on this issue, but simply you have to use Smartcon tools to check SDD temperature correctly in cases like this especially.

for GUI

```
sudo apt install gsmartcontrol
```

or in terminal

```
sudo smartctl -A /dev/sd(your drive letter) | grep -i temperature
```

This will show you either print correct temperature for your SDD/HDD